# GetSystemTimeZones missing GMT Standard Time

Tags: c#, .net, windows, timezone

I have been trying to use TimeZoneInfo.GetSystemTimeZones in .net4 to replace our old method which uses COM to call into some MFC code. However, I've had to revert to the COM method because GetSystemTimeZones doesn't return all time zones. Being based in the UK and not including GMT Standard Time in our list of options is a problem.

When I look in the registry, I find that *GMT Standard Time* has a *Dynamic DST* subkey with no rules defined. I downloaded the .net4 source code and, in TimeZoneInfo.cs,  GetSystemTimeZones eventually calls TryCreateAdjustmentRules which appears to return false if the *Dynamic DST* key has no FirstEntry or LastEntry defined.

```
            //
            // loop over all of the "<time_zone_name>\Dynamic DST" hive entries 
            // 
            // read FirstEntry  {MinValue      - (year1, 12, 31)}
            // read MiddleEntry {(yearN, 1, 1) - (yearN, 12, 31)} 
            // read LastEntry   {(yearN, 1, 1) - MaxValue       }

            // read the FirstEntry and LastEntry key values (ex: "1980", "2038")
            Int32 first = (Int32)dynamicKey.GetValue(c_firstEntryValue, -1, RegistryValueOptions.None); 
            Int32 last = (Int32)dynamicKey.GetValue(c_lastEntryValue, -1, RegistryValueOptions.None);

            if (first == -1 || last == -1 || first > last) { 
                rules = null;
                return false; 
            }
```

As TryCreateAdjustmentRules returns false, TryGetTimeZoneByRegistryKey throws an InvalidTimeZoneException which means *GMT Standard Time* doesn't get added into the time zone collection. I've tried deleting the empty *Dynamic DST* subkeys but something adds them back in again (probably Windows Update).

I've done alot of searching but haven't seen anyone else report this problem. I'm not sure whether there is a GetSystemTimeZones fix or whether I can stop the empty *Dynamic DST* subkey appearing in the first place. Any ideas?

Comment: That's extremely strange - "GMT Standard Time" is definitely returned for me. Could you post the code you're using to determine that it's missing? It's probably fine, but as we're seeing odd results...

Comment: I hate to say it but it works on my system, I'm in the UK and I see `GMT Standard Time` in the 101 values returned. Have you tried this on another system?

Comment: Jon, does your GMT Standard Time registry key have an empty Dynamic DST subkey?

Comment: @RichardHawkins: Where's the registry key I should look at, exactly? (And have you looked on other machines to see whether the registry key looks the same there, out of interest?)

Comment: @RichardHawkins: Don't worry, just found it. And no, my machine doesn't have a Dynamic DST subkey.

Comment: Lazarus, I'd be happy to find it is just my setup. I was aiming to use the code on two 2003 servers, two 2008 servers and a 2008 R2 server. Seemed to have the problem on all of them.

Comment: The missing piece of the jigsaw for me is what is putting in the empty Dynamic DST subkey? Whatever it is put it back in after I removed it so I'm guessing Windows Update?

Comment: @JonSkeet The code I'm looking at is in TimeZoneInfo.cs in the .net4 source posted by microsoft, I believe I got it from MSDN.

Comment: @RichardHawkins: It sounds like it's a bad registry entry, effectively. Are you using some sort of corporate Windows Update which  could have messed things up?

Comment: @JonSkeet Sorry, source is too big to post here. GetSystemTimeZones calls TryGetTimeZone which calls TryGetTimeZoneByRegistryKey which calls TryCreateAdjustmentRules which reads Dynamic DST subkey.

Comment: @RichardHawkins: I've never asked for the source code, but you've referred to it twice. Are you misreading my comments?

Comment: @JonSkeet We are not that big a company so do updates individually rather than using Group Policy.

Comment: @RichardHawkins: Okay. Well it sounds like you need to get to the bottom of why you've got an empty Dynamic DST subkey... possibly via regmon? (sysinternals)

Comment: @JonSkeet In your first comment you said "Could you post the code you're using to determine that it's missing?" I thought you meant the .net4 code. My code is    ListItem objListItem; 
   ReadOnlyCollection<TimeZoneInfo> timeZones = TimeZoneInfo.GetSystemTimeZones(); 
   IEnumerable<TimeZoneInfo> sortedTimeZones = timeZones.OrderBy(tz => tz.BaseUtcOffset);

   foreach (TimeZoneInfo timeZone in sortedTimeZones)
   {
                objListItem = new ListItem(timeZone.DisplayName, timeZone.Id);
                objTimeZonesList.Items.Add(objListItem);
   }

Comment: @RichardHawkins: Right, that's what I meant (although I've got a somewhat simpler little console app which just dumps all IDs :)

Comment: @Lazarus, since you're in the UK, does your GMT Standard Time have a Display DST subkey? Looking on my home Win7 machine it is not there so if I could find the culprit on my work machines it would be probably sort my problem.

Comment: Can you try to change the timezone on your system clock? It should list the same time zones that are available in the method you are calling. If it doesn't exist in the list for your clock, then that timezone is not installed.

Comment: We had a similar issue once when a client synchronized his online profile with the desktop application. Turned out his time zone settings in the registry were messed up. There a registry fix at http://bit.ly/HlSVOm. Does the problem still occur after running that?

Comment: @JensenSomers Thanks for the suggestion but I've looked at the reg file and it gives the same result as me removing the subkey. I've removed the Dynamic DST subkey a few times, the problem is it reappears and I'm not sure what is doing it. Until I find the culprit I'm sticking with my old code because if GMT is missing from my form it affects 99% of our customers.

Comment: @CharlesLambert The GMT time zone appears in the Windows time zone list and the server seems quite happy despite the extra subkey. It is only when I call the .NET function that I have the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that the problem is with our COM object and not with the .NET code. The code to read the registry should only be reading but it mistakenly calls RegCreateKey to optimise multiple calls to the same registry branch.

When the COM object is registered (with admin rights) because of a new version, it loads the time zones and creates *Dynamic DST* for the local time zone which in my case is GMT/UTC.

Administrators, I guess this question should be marked for deletion.

Comment: Ah ha! So it was the COM Object! :D

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing this is just a registry issue.

Something similar is outlined here for WinXP /  Server 2003 SP1.
Please see if the following helps:
http://blogs.technet.com/b/dst2007/archive/2007/03/06/missing-time-zones-in-registry.aspx

My guess is you could export the entire registry Key from another machine, and apply it to your problematic box(es).

Comment: My problem is that I can get rid of the _Dynamic DST_ subkey by deleting it in Registry Editor and the registry looks ok. At some later point the key reappears but this may be several days later. I just don't know what causes it to reappear. I will try using regmon on a test server to see if that gives any clues.

Answer (score 0):

After looking it over your problem and even running the code you provided in the comments to print out a list of Time Zones I am not able to get GMT to show up on my system. I am running Windows 7 Professional and selecting GMT is just not an option. I know that doesn't solve your problem and you - like a lot of other people - sound like you really need to get this to work with GMT.

However if at all possible, if you see a way to use UTC then I would check out these links:

[Windows 7 Lack of Support for GMT](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-desktop/time-zone-is-set-to-utc-i-need-gmt/683fd5fb-9eca-4cee-bbb8-b519a0673bf7)

[Converting UTC to GMT](http://home.hiwaay.net/~krcool/Astro/moon/gmt/)

Just another possible answer to your problem, is there anyway you can create a wrapper around the UTC values to display GMT? I ask because this problem doesn't seem like it is going to go away anytime soon. Even if you get it to work now - in the future it might break again. If I come up with a method for this I will update my answer.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but let me clarify. The key in the registry is _GMT Standard Time_ (the UK time zone) but the display text in the list of time zones is _(UTC) Dublin, Edinburgh, Lisbon, London_. UTC and GMT are two names for the same thing, Windows 2003 displays GMT while 2008 displays UTC.

Comment: This is a long shot, but have you tried un-registering your COM Object to see if that stops the key from showing back up?

Comment: I need my COM object for other functionality. As far as I am aware it only reads from this registry branch. I've now got Process Monitor looking at the registry to try to log who recreates it.